# Derivative in the direction of the outer normal on manifolds.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $(M,g)$ a riemannian manifold. If $u\in C^2(M)$ and we consider polar coordinates $(\rho,\theta)$, where $\rho>0$ and $\theta\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. Show that $u_\rho(\rho,\theta)$ is the derivative in the direction of the outer normal to the ball $B_\rho$, where the geodesic ball $B_\rho$ centered at $x\in M$ is $\{(s,\theta); s\in(0,\rho),\theta\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}\}$

My approach: I know that $n\cdot\nabla u=\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}$ in the euclidean case, but in the case of Riemannian manifold, if we take polar coordinates then a basis for the tangent space $T_x M$ are $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta^i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$, where $\theta^n=\rho$ and $\{\theta^i\}_{i=1}^{n-1}\in\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$. So, $$g\left(\nabla u,\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}\right)=\langle \nabla u,\frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}\rangle_g=\langle du, \frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}\rangle$$

Maybe, I'm little confused with the notion, but is true that $\langle du, \frac{\partial}{\partial\rho}\rangle=\frac{\partial u}{\partial\rho}$?

Comment: Yes. And the Gauss Lemma does tell you, after all, that $\partial/\partial\rho$ is the normal to the geodesic spheres centered at $x$.

Comment: @TedShifrin What a good observation! How do I use Gauss's lemma to prove that? Because, if $v,2\in B_\epsilon(0)\subset T_v T_pM\sim T_pM$ and $q=\exp_p(v)\in M$. Then, $\langle T_v\exp_p(v), T_v\exp_p(w) \rangle_q=\langle v,w\rangle_p$.